# disable checkbox after being checked

Tags: jquery

Please I need help on disabling a checkbox from being checked again after being checked first.

This is what I have done so far.

```
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="checked" onclick="check();"></label>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function check() {
          if($("#checked").is(":checked")){
             alert("Thanks for Attending");
            $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
          }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling check box and uncheck it using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108486/disabling-check-box-and-uncheck-it-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this snippet.

```js
function check() {
  if($("#checked").is(":checked")){
    alert("Thanks for Attending");
    //Code to disable checkbox after checked
    $('#checked').attr('disabled', true);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="checked" onclick="check();"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$(this).attr('disabled','disabled');

to

$('#checked').attr('disabled', true);
```

As $(this) not refers to checkbox because you are inside the function body.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative with vanilla js since you are trying to combine it with jQuery while you could not do so:

```
function check() {
    var el = document.getElementById("checked");

    if (el.checked) {
        el.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

If you still need jQuery version stick to `.prop()` usage:

```
function check() {
    var $el = $("#checked");

    if ($el.is(":checked")) {
        $el.prop("disabled", true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JqueryCheckboxChekedDisableCheckbox</title>
<style>
input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  height:10%;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
label {
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.error{
color:red;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<fieldset style="margin-left:20%;margin-right:20%;font-family:sans-serif;padding:15px;border-radius:5px;background:#f2f2f2;border:5px solid #1F497D">
<legend style="background:#1F497D;color:#fff;padding:5px 10px;font-size:22px;border-radius:5px;margin-left:20px;box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #ddd">JqueryCheckboxChekedDisableCheckbox</legend> 
<table>
    <tr><td>Subjects:</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="java"/>Java<input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="hibernate"/>Hibernate<input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="spring"/>Spring</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="send"/></td></tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
</html>
<script>
$('#send').on('click',function(){
    $("input[name='subject']").each(function(){
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).prop("disabled",true);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```