# If there a conditional statement or formula to Prevent the unchecking of a checkbox after it has been checked by a user?

Tags: javascript

Trying to write a clock in/clock out sheet to better track time. I'm going to share the sheet with my employees. I have it where the time stamp is locked after a checkbox is checked so no one can tamper with their time. But I want an employee to not be able to uncheck the box after they have checked it through their shared document and recorded their time. Wanting this incase they leave early then try to get paid for more time than they worked. I've found a script but it doesn't seem to be working at all, let alone the way I want it to.

For someone that a sheet is shared with to check a checkbox and then not be able to uncheck that checkbox

Comment: This is not the kind of policy that should be enforced inside a web page, as no matter what you do in JavaScript anybody can open up the developer tools and set the checkbox however they want. Your rule needs to be enforced on a secure server where users have to authenticate via username/password or some other scheme.

Comment: You may find this answer to a similar question helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38682112/17573919

Comment: How best do I go about this then? How would I enforce this over a secure server?

Comment: @Pointy  You are correct this should be enforced at the server end, client side is an open book to anyone with very little JS knowledge, but keeping the UI in sync, would certainly be nice too. :)

Comment: @WildernessAdventure Send a request to the server using AJAX to save the information that the checkbox has been clicked, but only on the event when it is initially clicked, then disabling the button and functionality of the button.

Comment: Honestly an application like this can turn out to be surprisingly complicated, because there may be all sorts of edge cases that come up. Any time a computer system rubs up against the reality of day-to-day life, things can get weird really quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments that the check for this should be done on the back-end/server as any user can bypass this on the front-end.
However as the most recent comment mentions it is nice to keep things in sync; this is one method to do what you ask.
It uses a class to determine which checkboxes to affect:

```js
function preventUncheck(element) { 
  element.checked ? element.disabled = true : null
}

document.querySelectorAll("input.disable-when-checked").forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener("change", () => { preventUncheck(checkbox) })
})
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="disable-when-checked" id="1" name="one" />
  <label for="1">I can't be unchecked</label>
</div>
<br />
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="normal" id="2" name="two" />
  <label for="2">I can be unchecked</label>
</div>
```